# Combining strings which have been altered

Tags: python, string, data-science

I have the following three strings:

```py
"A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial resection[intervention] to prevent recurrent endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.
"A randomized, prospective study of endometrial resection to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial polyps[condition] in women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.
"A randomized, prospective study of endometrial resection to prevent recurrent endometrial polyps in [eligibility]women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen[eligibility]. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.
```

Is there a way to efficiently combine the three strings into one, where you can see all the annotations (between brackets) that I have made? I cannot come up with anything efficient by myself. The result should look like:

```py
"A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial resection[intervention] to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial polyps[condition] in [eligibility]women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen[eligibility]. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to combine, what is the expected results? and what did you try to solve it?

Comment: @Guy I've updated the question with an example! Sorry for not including it. And I do not know, theoretically, how to approach it.

Comment: The generalized problem is solved by suffix trees, but if your problem is simpler than that, they might be overkill. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are only adding those words+brackets immediately next to the existing words (i.e. splitting the string on space won't change the alignment, which is the case in the example). A simple solution might be to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the split strings and keep the longest variant using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) back into a single string:

```
strings = ["A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial resection[intervention] to prevent recurrent endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.",
           "A randomized, prospective study of endometrial resection to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial polyps[condition] in women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.",
           "A randomized, prospective study of endometrial resection to prevent recurrent endometrial polyps in [eligibility]women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen[eligibility]. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.",
          ]

out = ' '.join([max(x, key=len) for x in zip(*map(lambda s: s.split(), strings))])
```

Output:

```
'A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial resection[intervention] to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial polyps[condition] in [eligibility]women with breast cancer receiving tamoxifen[eligibility]. To assess the role of endometrial resection in preventing recurrence of tamoxifen-associated endometrial polyps in women with breast cancer.'
```

If you need something more robust, a good starting point might be to use the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module to compute the successive differences, keeping the longest variant in each comparison.

Comment: I'm just adding the tags next to the words, so I guess this solution works just fine. Thank you so much :)